# How to unit test (with angular 5) a component that depends on the height of an element?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

I have a component with an input `fsElement`. this `fsElement` is supposed to be the id of any html element. Then my component uses this provided id to get the height of the element. Here is the relevant code:

```
export class BotaoTelaCheiaComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() fsElement:string;

  private _originalHeight: number;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    this._originalHeight = document.getElementById(this.fsElement).clientHeight; 

  }

}
```

when I run  `ng test` it fails with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientHeight' of null`. I am just runing the standard test that angular cli generates:

```
describe('BotaoTelaCheiaComponent', () => {
  let component: BotaoTelaCheiaComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BotaoTelaCheiaComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ BotaoTelaCheiaComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BotaoTelaCheiaComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

How do I rewrite this test or my component so it passes?

Comment: The question doesn't contain beforeEach section. Please, post all relevant code.

Comment: @estus editted, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lifecycle hooks (`OnInit`, etc) are triggered on first change detection which is performed in `beforeEach`.

In order to avoid that, `fixture.detectChanges()` should be removed from `beforeEach` and called on demand.

```
  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    component.fsElement = 'foo';
    spyOn(document, 'getElementById').and.returnValue({ clientHeight: 100 });
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(document.getElementById).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo');
    expect(component['_originalHeight']).toBe(100);
  });
```

Alternatively, a real DOM element with `id="foo"` can be added to DOM in `beforeEach` and removed in `afterEach`.

Direct DOM access complicates Angular testing because it requires to mock globals or DOM.

Comment: that solved it. could you just explain it to me ? the line `spyOn(document, 'getElementById').and.returnValue({ clientHeight: 100 });` seems to be forcing the clientHeight to 100. How does it do that? And how could I provide a real DOM element to the beforeEach? I think I might need to do that to write another test. Sorry if I'm missing something basic, I'm new to unit testing with angular...

Comment: This isn't specific to Angular. See [Jasmine documentation](http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html) for the explanation on spies. You can provide real DOM element the same way you would do with JS, `document.appendChild(..)` and so on. But you shouldn't provide real DOM element in unit tests. You're just testing the behaviour that is expected from real DOM. Real DOM is what integration and/or e2e tests are for.

Comment: The fact that you're using direct DOM access in Angular is possibly a mistake. You could pass element reference through input, use ViewChild, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the references, I will read them. I am actually using `@Input` to pass an Id so I can get a reference of the element... I didn't know i could pass an element directly, thanks :)

Comment: This depends where this element originates from. If it's an element that was created in parent component, then yes, passing element ref instead of id is the way to go. Notice that absolute element selectors (document.getElementById) will fail with native view encapsulation (shadow DOM).